# if and on the same line in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find a way to put this all on one line:

```
if Servers.empty?
  puts "Specify some servers in $@"
  exit
end
```

I tried this, but it does not work

```
puts "Specify from servers in $@" and exit if Servers.empty?
```

How would I go about putting that all on one line?

Comment: When in doubt, use parentheses. Also, why would you want to do that? I personally would find that hard to read.

Comment: do you want this to `STDERR` or `STDOUT`?

Comment: You can't chain it using `and` because `puts` returns `nil`

Comment: If you insist on a one-liner (without a semi-colon) and don't want to rely on `puts` returning `nil`, you could do this: `[[:puts, "Specify servers"],[:exit]].each { |a| send *a } if Servers.empty?`. Would I recommend this?  Let me think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
2.0.0-p451 :010 > (puts "Specify from servers in $@"; puts "exit") if [].empty?
Specify from servers in $@
exit
```

vs

```
2.0.0-p451 :011 > (puts "Specify from servers in $@"; puts "exit") if ['a'].empty?
 => nil
```

so in your case you would do...

```
(puts "Specify from servers in $@"; exit) if Servers.empty?
```

Answer (score 4):

Possible solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
abort("Specify some servers in $@") if Servers.empty? # To STDERR
```

**Solution 2**

```
class NoServerFound < StandardError; end

raise NoServerFound, "Specify some servers in $@" if Servers.empty?
```

Comment: The OP wants one-liners. You might want to change them to trailing if's.

Answer (score 3):

Why not wrap it in a method?

```
def exit_with(message)
  puts message
  exit
end

exit_with("Specify from servers in $@") if Servers.empty?
```

Answer (score 3):

`puts` returns `nil`, which is falsey, which is why your code doesn't work. If you want to use this trick, you are better off using `or` in this case...

```
puts "Specify from servers in $@" or exit if Servers.empty?
```

Comment: This is kinda abuse of the operator. It's better to use semicolon here :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
fail("Specify from servers in $@") if Servers.empty?
```

The `fail` is like your combination of `puts` and `exit` rolled into one. By default it raises a `RuntimeError` but you can pick any error or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not for `exit`, but in similar situations, I do it like this:

```
exit puts "Specify from servers in $@" if Servers.empty?
```

An actual case that I do it frequently is:

```
return puts "something went wrong" if blah_blah
```